# Navigation bar not showing on iOS web view

Tags: ios, uiwebview, navigation

When a user click the button non my app, it will load another view that contains a web view. However, the navigation is not showing up on the web view. Any suggestion?

Here is the code I use to load in the web view:

```
- (IBAction)visiteSite:(id)sender {  
    WebViewController *hospitalSite = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"hospitalSite"];
    hospitalSite.hospitalWebURL  = self.url;
    [self presentViewController:hospitalSite animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And on the Web view, I use this to load the actual content and generate the navigation bar:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    webView.frame = self.view.frame;
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL: self.hospitalWebURL]];
    [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    [[self view] addSubview:webView];
    webView.clipsToBounds =YES;
    webView.frame =  CGRectMake(0,64,webView.frame.size.width,webView.frame.size.height-64);

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0.8f;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:
                   [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[UIViewController alloc]
                           initWithNibName:@"hospitalSite" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                             initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    //Navigation controller init with ViewController as root
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

The website loads within the web view, but I just got an empty white bar on top instead of the navigation bar.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean to present the controller as modal? Perhaps it should be pushed on as follows?:

```
- (IBAction)visiteSite:(id)sender {  
    WebViewController *hospitalSite = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"hospitalSite"];
    hospitalSite.hospitalWebURL  = self.url;
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:hospitalSite animated:YES];
}
```

Also you might want to do your frame related code in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear rather than viewDidLoad, so that all view layout has happened. Otherwise some of the frame sizes may be wrong.